# Set second combobox value based on ajax call after selecting value in first combobox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, combobox

I have an entry form with two fields. A person and a division.

```
<input id="person_id" name="person_id">
<input id="division" name="division">
```

The following does some [Jquery EasyUI](https://www.jeasyui.com/) magic to pull a list of person names from the database.

```
$('#person_id').combobox({
        url:'person.php?action=namenlijst',
        valueField:'person_id',
        textField:'naam',
        editor:'{options:{required:true}}',
        onSelect: function(rec){
            var url = 'person.php?action=determine_division&id='+rec.person_id;
            //alert(url);
        $("#divisie").combobox("select",<value returned from ajax call); 
        }
});
```

And this code populates the division list with some values:

```
$('#divisie').combobox({
        url:'person.php?action=get_all_divisions',
        valueField:'division',
        textField:'division',
        editor:'{options:{required:true}}'
});
```

Division values are simple three letter strings. MPO, FPO, MA1 etc.

What I want to achieve is that when a person is selected that an Ajax call is made to determine the division a person last played in. Then set the selected value of the division input.

I've already added the onselect code and created the correct URL.

Questions:

1. How do I make the Ajax call and set the division input value to the
   value returned by my php function.
2. What should my php function return? A simple string value or some JSON string?

Comment: You need to create an ID field in both of those tables, so that way you give the person an id of HR123 in the person_id table as well as the division table there will be an entry with the id of HR123, when you make the call it should be a join call like so `SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN table1 WHERE table.id = table1.id` this is just a general example but take a look at this link to learn SQL joins. https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks, but question is about javascript and Ajax. The complexity of this particular database is of no concern here.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

```
$('#persoon_id').combobox({
        url:'persoon.php?action=namenlijst',
        valueField:'persoon_id',
        textField:'naam',
        editor:'{options:{required:true}}',
        onSelect: function(rec){
            var url = 'persoon.php?action=bepaal_divisie&persoon_id='+rec.persoon_id;
            $.ajax(url, {
                success: function(data) {
                     $("#divisie").combobox("select",data); 
                }
            });


        }
});
```